# Slackbot triggering actions and other bots

Tags: bots, slack

Slackbot can be configured to respond something when you say some selected key words. Can that feature be use to trigger actions.

For example, when I say `meeting`, can it execute the command `/todo @me meeting due today`?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup custom triggers for the slackbot, but it won't do what you're looking for because the todo-bot actions don't seem to trigger from another bot.

To setup custom slackbot responses you'd go to Customize Slack, then select the tab option for the Slackbot. From here, if the word in the left column is seen in a channel, slackbot will respond with the text on the right. It can't grab any info like the channel name or user name, just respond with text. This is useful for reminders like the wifi password or some brief custom help message.

Todo-bot now has webhooks. I haven't used it myself, but I've linked to the introduction page below. You can't do this entirely from within slack; An outside piece of software or server would need to be setup to monitor slack for triggers and create custom prefabricated todo's.
https://help.todobot.io/hc/en-us/articles/115010096748-Incoming-Webhooks